# Locate a TempVar in a MS Access main form and write it to a table connected to the subform

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I need to add some VBA code to a checkbox located on a subform of my front end Access 2016 database.

The goal is to insert to a table the value contained in a textbox located in the main form.

So far, the steps I took are:

1. Click on the checkbox located on the subform;
2. Create a temporary variable;
3. Insert the temporary variable into the related table;
4. Move on to the next item.

The code is the following:

```
    Option Compare Database

    Private Sub AssegnatoCampione_Click()

        'Create temporary variable and store the selected value
        TempVars("NumeroCampione").Value = Forms!FormCampioni2.SampleNo.Value

        'Write the value in the database
        CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO DB_Offerte2017 " _
                        & "([NumeroCampione]) VALUES " _
                        & "(" & TempVars![NumeroCampione] & ")" ', dbFailOnError
    End Sub
```

The error I get is: .

["Too few parameters. Expected 1."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZjK1.jpg)

Is there a way to know whether the variable is stored correctly or not?

Thank you so much for your help.

**Edit 1:**

Ok, so i guess that the error was due to DB_Offerte2017([NumeroCampione]) being a text field. I corrected the code in this way:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO DB_Offerte2017 ( NumeroCampione ) VALUES ('" & Me.Parent.SampleNo & "')", dbFailOnError
```

This way, every time I click on the check box, a new record is added in the table "DB_Offerte2017", under the field "NumeroCampione".

However, I need to add those records to the same row where the checkboxes is located (e.g. Click on checkbox where ID = 2438 -> Add "SampleNo" value on DB_Offerte2017.NumeroCampione where ID = 2438).

Is it possible to add a where statement in the code?

Comment: There is an unnecessary apostrophe in your Execute expression. Do you have a table for each year? Should be 1 table.

Comment: The database only collects data starting from January 1 2017. I’m using that particular table to store the line items listed in the purchase orders table. The purpose of this form is to let the users assign many items to one sample.

Comment: What do you mean by 'add those records to the same row'? A WHERE clause makes no sense for an INSERT action. What tables are the form and subform bound to? Why do you even need INSERT actions?

Comment: So, in the end the answer was absolutely correct. I posed the question in a wrong way, though. What I actually needed was to copy an information (the Sample Number) from the main form and paste it to a related record located in the subform. After you suggested the "parent" method, I realized it was actually much easier to work just within the form. I will paste the code later. Your answer was great, it helped me understand I was on an unnecessarily complicated path! Thanks a lot!

Comment: At first, I thought that the best way to achieve that goal was to use a temporary variable, store it on when clicking on the checkbox, and insert that value straight in the database.

Comment: If you have a form/subform arrangement and the main form and subform records are related, why do you need to copy SampleNumber to subform record?

Comment: The goal is to let different class of users (e.g. lab technicians) to flag each activity related to a sample. In this particular form, each form received by the lab administrative personnel is first recorded in the database, and then assigned a purchase order number. The lab technician will open a similar form, and flag (assign) all the activities that are needed to be done on the sample. The sample value is then stored on the Activities table and used in other queries. The entire process right now is done by hand and is quite effective though not as efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just a normal VBA variable or just reference the control? Code is behind subform and field/control on main form? Try:

`CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO DB_Offerte2017([NumeroCampione]) VALUES (" & Me.Parent.SampleNo & ")", dbFailOnError`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer! Yes, the code is assigned to a checkbox named "AssegnatoCampione". The control source is a YES/NO field named in the same way ("AssegnatoCampione"), located in the table named DB_Offerte2017. I tried the solution you proposed but it gives me the same error message. I think there's something wrong with my TempVar instruction.

Comment: I see you got the code to work with an adjustment for text delimiters.